# Enable Coding assistance for Node.js in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

For some reason, I can't enable "Coding assistance for Node.js".

My WebStorm version is 2019.3.

When I click on the checkbox it starts loading and after some time unchecks it again:

[image]

Comment: You should probably take this up with JetBrains. Start by upgrading WebStorm to see if it's a fixed issue.

Comment: I know that JetBrains support is often monitoring StackOverflow for that type of questions, so I decided to start here c:

I am upgrading webstorm rn hope it will help

Comment: They also monitor their own bug tracker, where it looks like this was already reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43088. Seems to have been fixed from 2019.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as simple as it can be, I just needed to update webstorm c:
Thanks, @jonrsharpe for pointing it out to me